# Resolving duplicate symbols in cocoapods, when using, JIRAMobieConnect and Appcelerator Framework?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, appcelerator, plcrashreporter, jira-mobile-connect

I need to use [JiraMobileConnect](https://cocoapods.org/?q=jiraConnect%201.2.1) and [Appcelerator](http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/guide/ios) frameworks in my project. I guess the Appcelerator framework internally is using the same [CrashReporter](https://plcrashreporter.org) as JiraMobileConnect and I get a lot of Duplicate symbols errors.
[image]

I see that CrashReporter Framework has this in the PLCrashReporterNamespace.h file,

```
/*
 * For external library integrators:
 *
 * Set this value to any valid C symbol prefix. This will automatically
 * prepend the given prefix to all external symbols in the library.
 *
 * This may be used to avoid symbol conflicts between multiple libraries
 * that may both incorporate PLCrashReporter.
 */
// #define PLCRASHREPORTER_PREFIX AcmeCo

#ifdef PLCRASHREPORTER_PREFIX
```

So I set a preprocessor Macros in JiraConnect target under Pods as `PLCRASHREPORTER_PREFIX=EM` , but now I get a undefined symbol error.

[image: Undefined symbols errors]

I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734638/prefixing-the-files-to-avoid-symbol-conflicts-between-external-frameworks), the answer says

> You need to recompile the corresponding framwork (all .c files) with
>   the same macro definition so that it exports and uses the modified
>   symbol names.

So is there any way other than downloading the PLCrashReporter source code and recompiling the library? Even if I do that, whats the way to make it work with cocoapods? I also found that there is a [PLCrashReporter pod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=name%3Aplcrashreporter*) , so I guess there must be a way to make all these conflicts go away , and am sure am not the first person face this exact or a similar problem. I would really appriciate if somebody can help me out here.